# AttributeError, whein writing back from ipython to Excel with pandas

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, error-handling

System:
Windows 7
Anaconda -> Spyder with 2.7.12 Python

I got this AttributeError:

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-d258b656588d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/xxx/.spyder/pandas excel.py', wdir='C:/xxx/.spyder')

  File "C:\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/xxx/.spyder/pandas excel.py", line 33, in <module>
    moving_avg.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Methodentest', startcol=12, startrow=38)

  File "C:\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2672, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Adjustmend of Data for Date funtioniert nicht?
#parsen = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m')

#Open new file object
xl = pd.ExcelFile('C:\xxx\Desktop\Beisspieldatensatz.xlsx')
#parse_dates={'Zeit': ['Jahr', 'Monat']}, index_col = 0,  date_parser=parsen)

#Link to specific sheet
df = xl.parse('Methodentest')

#Narrow the data input
df2 = df[['Jahr', 'Monat', 'Umsatzmenge']]

#Establishment values under the year 2015 
df3 = df2[(df2['Jahr']<2015)]

#Execute gleitender Mittelwert History 36 Month or 36 rows          
moving_avg = pd.rolling_mean(df3["Umsatzmenge"],36)
print (moving_avg.head())

#Create a pandas excel writer
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\xxx\Desktop\Beisspieldatensatz.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
moving_avg.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Methodentest', startcol=12, startrow=38)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

I want to read a data set in ipython from Excel. In the next step I want to "pare" my data, but this is not working?? (that's why I put this part in hashtag). After this I want do a mathematical method like here moving average for the next 18 month and store this information in moving_average.
My Data set start monthly from the 01.2012. Then the code must write back the new figures in Excel in specific row and column -> Here the error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to convert your `Series` back to a `DataFrame` before saving, try

```
moving_avg.to_frame().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Methodentest', startcol=12, startrow=38)
```

Comment: I try your approach and my whole excel file content is deleteted. The code should only update my excel file not erase the whole content!!! Do you have any solutions? (The calculation works and pastes the content in the right colum/row, but the header and primary key is also shown, i only want to see the results)

Comment: Sorry i didnt know that the write creates every time when it is started a complett blank sheet...